# Using zeep with xsd:choice

Tags: python, xml, xsd, wsdl, zeep

I have the following type

```
<xsd:element name="getDetail">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:choice>
                <xsd:element name="uno" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="dos" type="uct:DosType" />
                <xsd:element name="tres" type="uct:E164Type" />
                <xsd:element name="cuatro" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

So I have to choose one option of them. To do this I did follow the datastructure methods of the following link, mainly the **Nested using _value_1 method**

http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/datastructures.html

So the code I wrote is like this

```
element = client.get_element('ns2:getSubscriptionDetail')
element_value = element(_value_1={'uno' : 'numeroUno', 'dos':'numeroDos' , 'tres': 'numeroTres', 'cuatro': 'numeroCuatro'})
```

But when I run my python I get this error:

```
TypeError: {ns0}getSubscriptionDetail() got an unexpected keyword argument '_value_1'. Signature: `({uno: xsd:string} | {dos: {ns0}ImsiType} | {tres: {ns0}E164Type} | {cuatro: xsd:string})`
```

Why *value1* is unexpected as argument? Any ideas?

PD: My type getDetail has xsd:choice inside xsd:sequence and in the zeep documentation the types are upside down. Is this important? I cannot change my WSDL

Comment: I'm a little rusty on this, but I only make the observation that in the example, they have the property `maxOccurs` on `choice` and you don't. Could it matter?

Comment: Thanks, In the case it matters, I should use the simple method like this:
element_value = element(uno = 'numerouno')
but I get:
TypeError: Choice elements only work with keyword arguments